# TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-test-renderer

I am unit testing my react component using renderer of react-test-renderer. it was working fine, but after using ReactCssTransitionGroup I am getting the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined". not sure how to resolve this issue

I verified this issue is caused by ReactCssTransitionGroup

Below is my component file:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {List, ListItem, Spinner} from '@stores/reactCommon';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

import BagListItem from './bag-list-item';

const BagList = ({bagList, loading}) => {
  const items = bagList.map((item, key) => (
    <ListItem key={key}>
      <BagListItem
        upc={item.upc}
        price={item.sellingPrice}
        description={item.description}
      />
    </ListItem>
  ));
  return (
    <div className="bag-list">
      {loading ? (
        <span className="bag-list__spinner">
          <Spinner size="extra-large" />
        </span>
      ) : null}
      <div className="bag-list__story-default-spacer">
        <List maxHeight="70vh">
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="bagList"
            transitionAppear={true}
            transitionAppearTimeout={500}
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
          >
            {items}
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </List>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

BagList.propTypes = {
  bagList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool
};

export default BagList;
```

Below is my unit test file

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import BagList from '../../../../src/client/js/components/bag-list/bag-list';

describe('<BagList />', function() {
  this.items = [
    {
      upc: '123222123',
      sellingPrice: '12',
      description: 'this is a description'
    },
    {
      upc: '555123',
      price: '23',
      description: 'this is a description'
    }
  ];
  this.getComponent = items => {
    return <BagList bagList={items} loading={false} />;
  };

  it('Should render <BagList /> with bagList', () => {
    // this line is generating the error
    const items = renderer.create(this.getComponent(this.items)).toJSON();
    expect(items).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: can you either paste the full stack trace, or paste the piece of code where you read `myObj.baseVal` ?

Answer (score 3):

`react-addons-css-transition-group` is an old package that was [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-css-transition-group) in favor of `react-transition-group`.

v1 of `react-transition-group` was a drop-in replacement, but it was rewritten in v2.

You'll probably want to move to [`CSSTransition`](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) from the latest [`react-transition-group`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group).

---

Having said that, the error is coming from this code:

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
  if (element.classList) return !!className && element.classList.contains(className);else return (" " + (element.className.baseVal || element.className) + " ").indexOf(" " + className + " ") !== -1;
}
```

...in the `hasClass.js` module from the `dom-helpers` package included with the old `react-addons-css-transition-group`.

`react-test-renderer`...

> ...provides an experimental React renderer that can be used to render React components to pure JavaScript objects, without depending on the DOM or a native mobile environment

...so it doesn't implement everything provided by the DOM.

In this case it looks like `react-test-renderer` is not providing an implementation of `classList` on an `element` so calling `element.className.baseVal` throws the error you are seeing.

Comment: First of all thanks for your feedback. Now I have updated my code to "react-transition-group" v4 the previous error is resolved, but now I am getting a new error "TypeError: element.setAttribute is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error but it's produced by another scenario, my formatter added space after the JSX element {" "} in the Routes file (React Router DOM) causing the white screen of death .

```
<JSX.Element />{" "}
```

After removing the space the white screen of death and the error disappear.